# Passing for loop values as function parameters

Tags: go

It says: (no value) used as value, but I'm passing loop values from a slice to it!

```
package main

import "fmt"

func greet(n string) {
    fmt.Printf("Hi, %v\n", n)
}

func cycle(n []string, f func(string)) {
    for i := 0; i < len(n); i++ {
        fmt.Println(f(n[i]))
    }
}

func main() {
    cycle([]string{"John", "Marie"}, greet)
}
```

[Code snippet on Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/8aQFVtnxj2m)

Comment: Your `greet` function returns nothing, and you try to `fmt.Println` it. You possibly wanted `return fmt.Sprintf("Hi, %v\n", n)` in the `greet` instead?

Comment: I got this, I should have called the f() function directly not inside Println()

Comment: Great if you managed to solve your own problem, but please don't add a solution to your **question**. Instead, post it as an **answer**. I have removed the solution from your question.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution: I should have called the function directly, not inside Println().

```
package main

import "fmt"

func greet(n string) {
    fmt.Printf("Hi, %v\n", n)
}

func cycle(n []string, f func(string)) {
    for i := 0; i < len(n); i++ {
        f(n[i])
    }
}

func main() {
    cycle([]string{"John", "Marie"}, greet)
}
```